# Google Play Services 6.5.87 vs 7.3.0 - layout issues?

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-play-services

Ok, so here's a bizarre one... I have an activity with a bunch of fragments. I have some code which requires access to the fragment view. I get the fragment view using getView() method. Suddenly my code stopped working in between a few commits. After a very painful debugging process I've narrowed down the problem to the version of Google Play Services which changed from 6.5.87 to 7.3 in one of the commits.. Inspecting the layout hierarchy I can see that when my code works (i.e. getView() is returning a layout that I expect), there is an extra FrameLayout under my container, so the hierarchy looks like this:

```
<...stuff...>
  - FrameLayout (resource-id com.myapp:id/container)
    - FrameLayout (resource-id )
      - LinearLayout (resource-id )
        - LinearLayout (top level layout in my fragment)
```

When with 7.3 services this looks like:

```
<...stuff...>
  - FrameLayout (resource-id com.myapp:id/container)
    - LinearLayout (resource-id ) 
      - LinearLayout (top level layout in my fragment)
```

Any idea why there was a FrameLayout in the first place and where did it go in newer PlayServices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that earlier versions of Google Play Services injected an extra FrameLayout for their own special needs, and have now stopped doing this.

Perhaps it was for their "Please upgrade Google Play Services" dialog, who knows.

Is is very hard to answer this definitively since Google Play Services is closed-source. I ran into the same problem: I had code relying on Fragement getView() returning a FrameLayout, and this broke when I moved from using Google Play Services 6.1.x to 7.5.x